# Ignite Cache SQL query with field Object[] array

Tags: java, sql, ignite

I have a Ignite cache with the two classes below.

MyPerson class looks like this:

```
public class MyPerson implements Serializable
{
    @QuerySqlField()
    public String ID;

    @QuerySqlField()
    public Socials[] socials;
}
```

And the Socials class looks like this:

```
public class Socials implements Serializable
{
    @QuerySqlField()
    public String network;

    @QuerySqlField()
    public String login;
}
```

I create and populate the cache like this:

```
// creating person cache
CacheConfiguration<String, MyPerson> personCacheCfg = new CacheConfiguration<String, MyPerson>();
personCacheCfg.setName("Person");
personCacheCfg.setIndexedTypes(String.class, MyPerson.class);
IgniteCache<String, MyPerson> personCache = ignite.createCache(personCacheCfg);

// adding data
personCache.put("P1", new MyPerson("Person1", new Socials[] { new Socials("fb", "a@my.com"), new Socials("tw", "b.my.com") }));
personCache.put("P2", new MyPerson("Person2", new Socials[] { new Socials("tw", "c.my.com") }));
personCache.put("P3", new MyPerson("Person3", new Socials[] { new Socials("fb", "d.my.com") }));
```

Now, when I want to run a SqlFieldQuery that returns all Persons that have a specific Socials account, how would I do this with Ignite SQL? Would this be a join over the array field? Or is such case better done by storing the Socials in a separate cache?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't run SQL queries over nested collections or arrays. You should create an additional table of pairs `(socials, personId)` and run joins over these two tables.

Make sure to collocate data of these tables by `personId`. Otherwise you will need distributed joins, that impact performance dramatically. You can find documentation on affinity collocation here: https://apacheignite.readme.io/docs/affinity-collocation

Another option without use of SQL is a `ScanQuery`. But it requires a full data lookup. If you are going to select a big part of data anyway, scan query may be a good option too. Documentation: https://apacheignite.readme.io/docs/cache-queries#scan-queries